# How can I use SqlConnection.GetSchema to get synonym information?

Tags: c#, sql-server, schema

With code like this:

```
DataTable schema = conn.GetSchema();
DataTable tables = conn.GetSchema("Tables");
DataTable columns = conn.GetSchema("Columns");
```

Quite a lot of information can be fetched about the schema, but the metadata version (ie: GetSchema()) doesn't return anything about synonyms.

We use Synonyms quite heavily in our environment.  Can I get Schema information about them using GetSchema, or do I need another method?

Comment: GetSchema() is a very poor thing that reports like 5% of a given database information (it's even tworst for other DB than for SQL Server). I suggest you use `sys.synonyms` wich is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189458.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not a schema collection for Synonyms for SQL Server:

[SQL Server Schema Collections](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There does appear to be a way to override the collections with .NET 3.5.  I have never done this though so I don't know if it actually works.  The basic idea is that you create an XML file to define how `getschema` defines and queries for schema data.  You then change your applications configuration to use this XML file to override the collections that are available.

[GetSchema Override](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Dd283134%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

There are examples in the provided link to add a Primary Keys collection to the schema.  It looks promising if your determined to use `getschema`.  Otherwise you could create your own schema functions and just query sys.synonyms to get synonyms.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for late response.  I was afraid of this.  I appreciate the suggestion but for the limited use that I'm making of this, I think I'll revert to the old trick of writing a query to read the information schema views.